# concatenate lists in python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a 3x2 list called `x` and a 1x2 list called `y`:

```
x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

and

```
y=[10,20]
```

**my question is how to concatenate `y` to the end of `x` to end up with a 4x2 list like:**

```
x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[10,20]]
```

I've tried this:

```
xx=[x,y]
```

but it gives me this which is not a 4x2 list:

```
xx=[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[10,20]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> x.append([10, 20])
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [10, 20]]
```

Or:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> x += [[10, 20]] # a list with a list as its only element
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [10, 20]]
```

Answer (score 9):

Given:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
y = [10,20]
```

this:

```
x.append(y)
```

will give you:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [10, 20]]
```

**Note** however that this *modifies* `x`.

If you *don't* want to modify `x`, this is another way:

```
 xx = x + [y[:]]
```

setting `xx` to:

```
 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [10, 20]]
```

We use `y[:]` rather than simply `y` in the above assignment because we want to create separate copy of `y` for `xx` so later, should (the original) `y` be modified it would not lead to changes in `xx`.

Comment: Note that even in your second example you can indirectly modify `xx` by modifying `y`.  (e.g. `xx = x + [y]; y.append(3)`).

Comment: @mgilson Ah .. good catch, thanks. I'll update my answer with either a cautionary note or a code fix shortly.

Comment: It does address my comment, although I would probably add a sentence to the answer saying why you used `[y[:]]` instead of just `[y]`.  That way, the OP (or anyone else who comes across this) can have all the information necessary to pick which form is more appropriate for their application.  My guess is that creating a shallow copy is probably unnecessary here, but the question is a little too vague to really know for sure.

Comment: :^)  Well take your time then and enjoy your noodles!

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> y=[10,20]
>>> x.append(y)  # or x.append(list(y)) to append a shallow copy of y
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [10, 20]]
```

Comment: @JonClements -- While you're (mostly) correct, it does have a *slightly* different meaning.  Using `list(y)` means that changes to `y` won't show up in `x`.  In other words, `list(y)` appends a (shallow) copy of `y` instead of the actual object.

Comment: @mgilson Yup - I'm aware of that. But then, since the OP wasn't massively clear, it's more likely a simple append is fine, and `y` can just go its merry way somewhere else. Ashwini has made a good comment and update here... so +1 from me for this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a new list:

```
z = x + [y]
```

Note, that using `[y]` makes the content a list within a list, so that this works.

If you want to modify `x` inplace, then:

```
x.append(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't use it often myself, I think it's worth mentioning the list's ***extend*** member function:

```
>>> x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> y=[10,20]
>>> x.extend([y])
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [10, 20]]
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists